# Converting pointers to boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost\interprocess\file_mapping.hpp>

file_mapping* fm = new file_mapping(FilePath,read_only);
```

How can I convert this line to use `boost::shared_ptr`?

Whenever I attempt `shared_ptr<file_mapping>` I then get compile errors on the right hand side with the `new` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor of `shared_ptr<T>` is `explicit`: you don't want to have a `shared_ptr<T>` accidentally taking ownership of your `T*` and `delete` it when done. Thus, you need to explicitly construct a `shared_ptr<T>` from the pointer, e.g.,

```
boost::shared_ptr<file_mapping> ptr(new file_mapping(FilePath, read_only));
```

... or even something like

```
std::shared_ptr<file_mapping> ptr = std::make_shared<file_mapping>(FilePath, read_only);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
boost::shared_ptr<file_mapping> fm_ptr(new file_mapping(FilePath, read_only));
```